# There was a problem authenticationg with your cluster. when i making gitlab and k8s cluster integration

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab-ci, kops

I create k8s cluster in aws by using kops

i wrote kubernetes cluster name : `test.fuzes.io`

api url : `https://api.test.fuzes.io/api/v1`

and i fill the CA Certificate field with result of

`kubectl get secret {secrete_name} -o jsonpath="{['data']['ca\.crt']}" | base64 --decode`

and finally i fill the Service Token field with result of

`kubectl -n kube-system describe secret $(kubectl -n kube-system get secret | grep gitlab-admin | awk '{print $1}')`

but when i save changes, i got message

`There was a problem authenticating with your cluster. Please ensure your CA Certificate and Token are valid.`

and i can't install helm tiller with kubernetes error:404

I really don't know what i did wrong. please help me....

Comment: Can you list all service accounts, roles and role bindings `kubectl get sa,roles,rolebindings --all-namespaces`

Comment: @A_Suh it works well... when deleted and created cluster again... i don't know what's the problem. thank you for your interest

Comment: @A_Suh Delete the cluster and create it again don't work for me!?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @fuzes confirmed cluster re-creation can be a workaround for this issue.

This was also described on a GitLab Issues - [Kubernetes authentication not consistent](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ee/issues/8897)

In short:
Using the same Kubernetes cluster integration configuration in multiple projects authenticates correctly on one but not the other.

Another suggestion to work around this by just setting [CI Variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/) (`KUBE_NAMESPACE` and `KUBECONFIG`) instead of using our Kubernetes integration.

Hope this will be helpful for future references.

Answer (score 1):

1. Adjust the api URL to https://api.test.fuzes.io:6443 (6443 is the default port kube master listens on for the api-server , if you have it edited then use the custom one )
   use this command to validate the port "kubectl cluster-info | grep 'Kubernetes master' | awk '/http/ {print $NF}' "

This command will print the api-server url , you can add it directly in the asked column

2. Next , for your CA certificate ensure you copy all the command output along with BEGIN CERTIFICATE and END CERTIFICATE

with this you will be able to add the cluster

Answer (score 0):

```
kubectl cluster-info | \
    grep 'Kubernetes master' | \
    awk '/http/ {print $NF}' 

return https://control.pomazan.xyz/k8s/clusters/c-t7qr5
```

But use like `https://80.211.195.192:6443` as API URL.

Answer (score -3):

```
  {"kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {

  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "forbidden: User \"system:anonymous\" cannot get path \"/\"",
  "reason": "Forbidden",
  "details": {

  },
  "code": 403
}
```

This question is appeared in many people's environment, finally can be resolved!!!