# Trying to get (bare-metal) kubernetes cluster linked to Gitlab to test CI

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab

Trying to get kubernetes cluster linked to Gitlab to test CI.

Following the [instructions here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/clusters/#add-existing-kubernetes-cluster), but get the following:

> There was a problem authenticating with your cluster. Please ensure your CA Certificate and Token are valid.

I've tried deleting the cluster and setting up again ([suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56732383/there-was-a-problem-authenticationg-with-your-cluster-when-i-making-gitlab-and)) - but this hasn't made a difference.

Using the same `$TOKEN`, the following curl command works fine from another machine

```sh
curl -X GET $APISERVER/api --header "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" --insecure
```

Grateful for any help with sorting this.

Comment: Did you try workaround by setting CI Variables described in discussion section here https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/issues/8897/ ?